# Regex to get the word next to all of the given words

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to capture the word immediately next to all of the words I provide.

Example Sentence:

> user="panda" is trying to access resource="system"

Words to be captured: panda & system (i.e., the word immediately next to the words 'user' & 'resource')

Currently, I use this regex `(?<=name=\")(.*?)(?=\";)` which returns the name 'panda'. I'm looking for a query that would capture both the user and the resource in the above sentence.

Can someone help with the regex query to do this?

Comment: What programming language / regex engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using C#'s Regex.Replace() operation.

Comment: You may use `(?<=(?:user|resource)=\").*?(?=\")`. [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3auser%7cresource%29%3d%5c%22%29.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5c%22%29&i=user%3d%22panda%22+is+trying+to+access+resource%3d%22system%22).

Comment: Awesome! That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET's regex supports non-fixed length Lookbehinds, you can just add all the words you want in a non-capturing group and use alternation:

```
(?<=(?:user|resource)=\").*?(?=\")
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3Auser%7Cresource%29%3D%5C%22%29.%2A%3F%28%3F%3D%5C%22%29&i=user%3D%22panda%22%20is%20trying%20to%20access%20resource%3D%22system%22).

You can also get rid of the Lookahead by using something like this:

```
(?<=(?:user|resource)=\")[^"]*
```

[Demo #2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3Auser%7Cresource%29%3D%5C%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D*&i=user%3D%22panda%22%20is%20trying%20to%20access%20resource%3D%22system%22)

Answer (score 1):

just a simple regex with lazy matching should do the job

```
user="(.*?)".*resource="(.*?)"
```

it gets more complicated if you need to match more than two words in any order, I wouldn't use a RegEx in this case at all, you would rather want to make a lexer for that. Just make a class/procedure that will tokenize the sentence first, then parser to get the information you want

Comment: Thanks, it works but it returns a 'Full match' and two groups of output. The full match contains everything from 'user' to 'resource'. The two groups contain the words 'panda' and 'system'. Is there a way to get just the groups without the full match?

Note: I tried this regex in both regex101.com and in my IDE. I get the same result as I've mentioned here.

Comment: Btw, I am happy to match just these two words. I am using successive regex calls currently, thought of doing both in a single invocation.